# Can't download pdf file from server

Tags: php, http-headers

I'm trying to force a PDF to download when a link is clicked but I keep receiving headers warnings and weird characters from the readfile.

The `<a>` tag:

```
 <p>The pdf file is large and can take a minute to download.
 You can <a href="/icisherbrooke/downloadAnnuaire.php">click here to download the pdf.</a></p>
```

The download.php file:

```
<?php

$fullpath = 'annuaire_2013-14_optimized3.pdf';

if(file_exists($fullpath)){
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="annuaire_2013-14_optimized3.pdf"');

    readfile($fullpath);
    exit();
}

?>
```

When I replace the headers and readfile by a `echo "test"`, it works.

Instead of the download prompt, I'm redirected to download.php. Here is a part of the result for download.php:

`Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/kanope/vhost_file/info-rapide.com/icisherbrooke/downloadAnnuaire.php:1) in /home/kanope/vhost_file/info-rapide.com/icisherbrooke/downloadAnnuaire.php on line 8
%PDF-1.6 %���� 1561 0 obj <> endobj 1575 0 obj <>/Filter/FlateDecode/ID[<0EC5F18608359D479CC3DB0FF72E23C8><997B135B48FBE541BDE876EE8BECFD9D>]/Index[1561 20]/Info 1560 0 R/Length 95/Prev 216592620/`

Comment: Sounds like you have some whitespace on line 1. Maybe a BOM.

Comment: You are right, it was indeed a BOM. I changed the encoding in Notepad++ to UTF8 without BOM and the new file works. If you were to post this as an answer I could accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error indicates, there is some output on line 1. It's usually whitespace. If you don't see any whitespace, check for a BOM. :)